# How to maximize and minimize a div (no jquery only javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

hello I need to maximaze or minimize a div in my html page using only javascript no jquery i wanna be able to do like this http://jsfiddle.net/miqdad/Qy6Sj/1/

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    if($(this).html() == "-"){
        $(this).html("+");
    }
    else{
        $(this).html("-");
    }
    $("#box").slideToggle();
});
```

this is exactly how i want it to be but no jquery

but with no jquery only javascript, can someone please help me, I googled this everywhere and couldnt find the answer

Comment: Consider [`<details>`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details). Only HTML, no JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

a simple google search came up with:

```
https://www.itcodar.com/javascript/expand-div-on-click-with-smooth-animation.html#:~:text=How%20to%20display%20a%20div%20with%20a%20smooth,transition%20must%20include%20the%20change%20of%20height.%20Thus%3A
```

```js
function seeMore() {
  const text = document.getElementById('website-info-idea')
  const text2 = document.getElementById('website-info-technical')
  text.classList.toggle("show")
  text2.classList.toggle("show")
}
```

```css
.col {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.col.show {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 23px;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

#a1 {
  display:inline-block;
  border: solid 2px black;
}
```

```html
<div id='a1'>
  <a onclick="seeMore()" class="btn btn-secondary btn-md btn-custom">About this Website</a>

  <div class="col" id="website-info-idea">Idea</div>
  <div class="col" id="website-info-technical">Technical</div>
</div>
```